# how to construct graph from house price prediction dataset

Tags: python, graph, networkx, gnn

I have a dataset of house price predictions.

| House id | society_id | building_type | households | yyyymmdd | floor | price | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 204 | a9cvzgJ | 170 | 185 | 01/02/2006 | 3 | 43000 | 01/02/2006 |
| 100 | a4Nkquj | 170 | 150 | 01/04/2006 | 13 | 46300 | 01/04/2006 |

the dataset has the shape of (2000,40)
while 1880 rows have same house id.
I have to make heterogenous graphs from dataset. the metapaths are as follows:
[image: Metapath]

here BT stands for building type, where H1 and H2 represents house 1 and house 2.
the meta graph example is:

[image: meta graph]

I know of network X. it allows dataframe to graph [function](https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_dataframe.html) . but i don't know how can i use in my scenario. the price column is target node.

A glimpse of dataset

[image: a glimpse of dataframe]

any guidance will mean a lot.
thank you. The goal is to make adjancy matrix of dataset

Comment: Where exactly does the GI node come from?

Comment: thank you for responding, GI stands for geographical information. its another node in dataset just like building type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build a graph like M_1 using only one attribute (such as building type), you could do either of the following. You could use the `from_pandas_edgelist` as follows:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df2, source = 'house_id', target = 'buidling_id')
```

or you could do the following:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(df.loc[:,['house_id','building_id']].to_numpy())
```

If you have a list of graphs `glist : [M_1,M_2,...]` each of which connects house_id to one other attribute, you can combine them using the compose_all function. For instance,

```
G = nx.compose_all(glist)
```

Alternatively, if you have an existing graph made using certain attributes, you can add another attribute with

```
G.add_edges_from(df.loc[:,['house_id','new_attribute']].to_numpy())
```